# graph api This post could not be loaded

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Get i post in my page from graph api.

It is a shared posts.

```
Object
   created_time: "2015-12-13T06:51:37+0000"
   id: "9177623449602......"
   story: "... shared people's video.""
```

I'm getting success

So, I Need action's delete it.

I acions like

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/9177623449602......?access_token={PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

but , facebook result is :

```
"(#100) This post could not be loaded"
```

It is why?

Normal post delete was success.

But shared posts ( has story field ) can not work.

please help me.